# Pivot Table in Hive and Create Multiple Columns for Unique Combinations

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I want to pivot the following table

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  date         |   qty   | 
 | 1    |    A     |   1/1/19      |   11    | 
 | 1    |    A     |   2/1/19      |   12    |
 | 2    |    B     |   1/1/19      |   13    |
 | 2    |    B     |   2/1/19      |   14    |
 | 3    |    C     |   1/1/19      |   15    |
 | 3    |    C     |   3/1/19      |   16    |
```

into

```
 | ID   |   Code   |  mth_1(1/1/19)  |   mth_2(2/1/19)  | mth_3(3/1/19)   |   
 | 1    |    A     |   11            |     12           |   0             |
 | 2    |    B     |   13            |     14           |   0             |  
 | 3    |    C     |   15            |     0            |   16            |
```

I am new to hive, i am not sure how to implement it.

```
NOTE: I don't want to do mapping because my month values change over time.
```

Comment: there is no `pivot` functionality in Hive. even if it were allowed, it looks like you would need a dynamic pivot as the number of dates isn't fixed.

Comment: is ther eany solution have you got ? @Sai